# Node.js - Compressing data on server, sending it via Engine.IO Web Sockets, and decompressing it on client

Tags: node.js, zlib, engine.io

I GZip some JSON data on server, send it via Engine.IO implementation of Web Sockets

```
function sendResourceDataToObserver(socket, data) {
  zlib.gzip(data, function (_, result) {
    socket.send(result);
  });
}
```

and decompress it with ZLIB module that I import with Browserify (http://browserify.org/)

```
socket.on('message', function (data) {
        zlib.gunzip(data, function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
          }
          console.log(decoded);
        });
});
```

However I get this error ('decoded' is obviously undefined):

```
Error: invalid file signature:,�
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at nb.i (http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:1994:184)
    at Bb (http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:2000:424)
    at http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:2000:338
    at http://localhost:5000/bundle.js:1869:21
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the zlib compress library is 100% pure JavaScript?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/brianloveswords/zlib-browserify/issues/6) seems relevant.

Comment: Tried with https://github.com/brianloveswords/zlib-browserify and https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js as well but still no luck. Getting similar errors.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?